# Apache Rewrite not rewriting as expected

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewritecond

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to redirect users to the HTTPS equivalent URL unless the URL is for my Jenkins CI server.  Here is the rule I have in my default site config (my Jenkins and other sites have their own respective `VirtualHost` entries:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerAdmin support@example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.+/jenkins/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: As requested, here is the output from `apache2ctl -S`:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server ip-10-72-226-167.ec2.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:2)
         port 443 namevhost ip-10-72-226-167.ec2.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:2)
         port 443 namevhost qa.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example-ssl:2)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server ip-10-72-226-167.ec2.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost ip-10-72-226-167.ec2.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost qa.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/jenkins:1)
Syntax OK
```

What I am expecting is that when I browse to `http://qa.example.com` that I get re-directed to `https://qa.example.com/`, but if I browse to `http://qa.example.com/jenkins/` then my Jenkins config kicks in.  The latter works, but the former does not, i.e. browsing to `http://qa.example.com/` does not re-direct me to `https://qa.example.com/`.

Comment: Please provide the output from `apache2ctl -S`.  What behavior do you see instead of what's expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting those rules in the `_default_` vhost, put them in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/jenkins` vhost, so that it can work against requests that have been mapped to that name.

Also - the expression on your second `RewriteRule` won't ever match `/jenkins/`, since it's requiring at least one character before the leading slash.  Try this:

```
ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/jenkins/.*$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```